# Bamboo for code versioning

Tags: bamboo

Hi I'm new to this tool 'Bamboo' and would like to know whether this tool can be used for code versioning control or not ? or it need 3rd party code versioning tool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still need 3rd party source control system for your project, like git. Bamboo is just continuous integration service, they can work together.

Comment: Thanks for your comment